# not getting correct height in ng-init after ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
       $scope.checkbioheight = function () { 
  var h = $('.c').outerHeight();
        console.log(h);
        if (h > 60) {
           //do something
        } else  {
            //do something
        }
}
<p ng-cloak ng-bind-html="renderHtml(ViewAboutCoach)" class="c" data-ng-init="checkbioheight()" ></p>
```

I am getting 5px height from console.log, 
After data loaded its actually 229px. Why it returns wrong. And if i must use settimeout so whats the benefit of angular JS, i could have use jquery for this.

Comment: _i could have use jquery for this._ - but you're using jquery `$('.c').outerHeight();`

Comment: i mean for all of this. i can use "mutation observer". please understand my question.

Comment: the real height of the DOM will be available when it will be rendered, and it will be rendered after the code that adds it finished executing.

Answer (score 0):

From angular 1.5.x you can use life cycle hooks in your application.
If you make a component then you can use $postLink()

More information on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

In another way you can try with this

```
 $timeout(function(){
    var h = $('.c').outerHeight();
    console.log(h);
    if (h > 60) {
       //do something
    } else  {
        //do something
    }});
```